# [Java]Do we need connection pool if we only use 1 connection?

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to ask, if I am going to use a single connection in the whole program, do I need to use a connection pool? Does using a connection pool give me better performance?
For example, I may open a static connection and use it for multiple sql query, then finally when the program finish, I close the connection.  Most of the program I am dealing with, are not multi-threaded, so I don't see the benefit of using connection pool in such situation. Would anyone can answer my question, thank you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider using a connection pool that offers you better connectivity i.e. will wait for the DB server to recover from a restart and then connect again. Connection pools also ping the database server regularly to check if everything is alright, perform other connectivity tests, retry connections, log useful information and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, I may open a static
>   connection and use it for multiple sql
>   query, then finally when the program
>   finish, I close the connection. Most
>   of the program I am dealing with, are
>   not multi-threaded

Sounds like you don't need a connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever need a connection pool.

It can be useful if you require enforcement on having a limit number of connections.